# Finding all the correct and incorrect characters in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, logic

I am writing a code where I want to check if any of the entered character values belong in the array above.If it doesn't have the letter i want to add +1 to e. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char word[10] = { 'H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e' };
bool f1(char x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (x == word[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char x;
    int e = 0, k = 1;
    while (k <= 10) {
        cin >> x;
        if (f1(x) != true)
            e++;
        k++;
    }
    cout << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the result is either e=0 or e=10 with me having entered characters that are in the array and vice verse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the character isn't found, what does `f1` return then?

Comment: Your function `f1()` exposes _undefined behavior_ (you should have gotten a compiler warning). Not all paths of the code return a value.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  That would have pointed out the problem.

Comment: `return false;` is not implicit at the end of `f1()`, you have to add it after the _for_

Comment: `[...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function. [...]`

Comment: `char word[10] = { 'H', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e' };` why 10 ? that time be lazy doing `const char * word = "House";` ... and change loop end condition !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all code paths of your function `f1` return a value; Actually your compiler should have told you about this. So if your character is not found (i.e. the loop comes to its end), then it is undefined (behaviour) what the function will return. If it returns `true`, then this is the behaviour you are observing. Note, however, that the function may return anything in this case, so you cannot rely on this behaviour.

Write

```
bool f1(char x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (x == word[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and it should work.

BTW: note that C-function `strchr` offers a very similar functionality (although it works only for `0`-terminated strings then).